# Adding an autocompletion script to ZSH seems not to be working

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion, prezto

I have a Git repository, `omni`.

`omni` is checked out at `~/omni`.

There is a completion script at `~/omni/completions/_omni`.

I set `fpath=( ~/omni/completions $fpath )`, via `~/.zprofile` so the completion script should get picked up but is not.  This is trivially proven:

```sh
$ for dir in "$fpath[@]"; do if [ -f "$dir/_omni" ]; then echo $dir; fi; done
/Users/myusername/omni/completions
```

I have also run `compinit -i` to initialize completion, but the script does not get picked up.

```sh
$ compinit -i

$ which _omni
_omni not found
```

However, if I re-initialize the completion, everything works

```
$ which _omni
_omni not found

$ compinit -i

$ which _omni
_omni not found

$ compinit -u

$ which _omni
_omni () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
```

Now the completion script gets picked up.

What do I need to do so that the completion script gets picked up automatically when the shell starts, when `compinit -i` runs?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been something to do with permissions, as all of the files (and their parent directories) were marked 777.

```
chmod -R go-rwx ~/omni
```

Seems to have resolved the issue.